# Magento2 Multi store problem

Tags: magento2, product, admin, multistore, configuration

> I have created three websites within a single Magento instance.

[image]

> All three store is showing in configuration it means are enable and active.

[image]

I have put Magento version `2.3.3` with sample data.

When I Create/Edit product admin show only one website view which is a default.

1. Why there is only one website?
2. How can I create products within two remain websites?

[image]

Comment: Have you check console or log file when go to product section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using the New Product function and page, you must first visit the configuration page for the Site that you want the product to pertain to.

```
Stores > All Stores > [select Web Site] >
```

On that config page, check the **Set as Default** button.

Now start the Add New Product process.

Way down the Product configuration page there's a setting for "Product in Websites", on which you can set which Websites the product is available on. (And not to be confused with the Categories setting and mechanism.)

It looks like the "Set as Default" (Website) preselects that Website in the "Product in Websites" settings.

You can use "Product in Websites" to add one or more additional sites. After saving that setting, the product config page will then display a Scope control at top left, including scopes for those sites.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow below steps :

- I have also 2 websites, Please check below screenshot.

[image]

- When I go to my product, which I have installed using Magento Sample Data, I can see only single website is available there. Please check screenshot.

[image]

- Now scroll down into that product and go to "**Product in websites**" tab. Please check below screenshot.

[image]

- And there is only one website is assigned which is default. I just recently created new website "Demo" that is not assigned there.
- So please select new website checkbox and save that product and then check that dropdown. Please check below screenshot.

[image]

- Now I can see that website is available in that dropdown.
- So if you want to assign all products then go to Product's Grid and then select all products and select action "Update Attributes". There is one tab available called "Websites", click on that and select your new website's checkbox there. Please check below screenshot.

[image]

- And click on "Save button".
- After that please run below command once

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

- That's it. Now you can able to see your products in another website as well.

Hope this will help you!